# Google form: getting entry id of email

Tags: google-forms

The rest of the fields can be obtained by inspecting elements except the `email` field.

How do I get the entry id even if it's not pre-filled?

As you can see the image below, we can get the entry id of a short text, except the email:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Took a bit, but finally figured it out: emailAddress.

Unlike the others that require "entry.xxxxxx", this one's a little different.